# How can I stop printing a string at a varying index?

Tags: java, string

As a starter project, I'm making a code that writes out digits of pi. The code prompts for an int, and prints that many decimal places of pi, which uses a predetermined string. The problem is that each individual digit is on a separate line, like this:

> 3
>   .
>   1
>   4
>   1
>   5
>   9

That code used a *for* loop that ends at the index that is given by the scanner. It printed one character at a time. I'm struggling to find a way to make the code print ten-digit substrings of pi separately, each on their own line, meaning 26 digits would be printed like this:

> 3 .
>   1415926535
>   8979323846
>   264338

That is two sets of ten, and a third set containing the remaining six. I'm struggling to divide the string printing into groups of ten, and still have the printing stop at the given index, even if that index is not a multiple of ten. In addition, the *for* loop from the old code is being used for a digit counter, so I would like to keep it. Placing "/n" into the string to make spaces interrupts the counting system, as those characters are counted and printed as well, invalidating that option. Thus far I haven't had any other ideas to fix this. If you know of a way to print in this fashion, let me know. My code is below, feel free to copy it and experiment, and credit me if you decide to use it somewhere.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PiWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String pi = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679";
        Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many decimal places of pi do you want to see?\nEnter an integer less than or equal to 100");
        int stopAt = theScanner.nextInt();
        char currentChar;
        int num0 = 0;
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        int num4 = 0;
        int num5 = 0;
        int num6 = 0;
        int num7 = 0;
        int num8 = 0;
        int num9 = 0;
        //Causes the code to ignore the "3." at the start.
        stopAt = stopAt + 2;
        for (int loopNum = 0; loopNum < stopAt; loopNum++) {
            System.out.println(pi.charAt(loopNum));
            currentChar = pi.charAt(loopNum);
            //This counts how many times a digit occurs.
            switch (currentChar) {
                case '0':
                    num0++;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    num1++;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    num2++;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    num3++;
                case '4':
                    num4++;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    num5++;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    num6++;
                    break;
                case '7':
                    num7++;
                    break;
                case '8':
                    num8++;
                    break;
                case '9':
                    num9++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        //Further ignores "3."
        num3--;
        //Corrects number for message.
        stopAt = stopAt - 2;
        System.out.println("Successfully printed first " + stopAt + " decimal places of pi.\nShow digit count?\nY/N");
        theScanner.nextLine();
        char response = theScanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (response == 'y'||response == 'Y') {
            //This displays how many times each digit occurred.
            if (num0 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 zero");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num0 + " zeroes");
            }
            if (num1 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 one");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num1 + " ones");
            }
            if (num2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 two");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num2 + " twos");
            }
            if (num3 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 three");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num3 + " threes");
            }
            if (num4 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 four");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num4 + " fours");
            }
            if (num5 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 five");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num5 + " fives");
            }
            if (num6 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 six");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num6 + " sixes");
            }
            if (num7 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 seven");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num7 + " sevens");
            }
            if (num8 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 eight");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num8 + " eights");
            }
            if (num9 == 1) {
                System.out.println("1 nine");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(num9 + " nines");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a pre-determined string for pi or are you calculating it each time?

Comment: I'd test whether I've reached a multiple of ten digits using the `%` modulo operator, and depending on that I would either use `print` or `println` to display the digit

Comment: You only have to add the new line in the output, not in the original pi string

Comment: Please post the code you tried to implement. So that we can check on where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid counting logic by instead doing a little math, a couple of basic loops, and the use of `print` vs `println`. To start, I'd define the variables in use here:

```
//constants
int DIGITS_PER_LINE = 10; //your number of digits per line
int DIGITS_OFFSET = 2; //always 2, because 0 = '3' and 1 = '.'
String pi = /* your PI string */;

//input
int decimals = 42; //for example, from the user
```

Then, print the result using the loop:

```
//We can calculate the number of lines we need from the start
int lines = decimals / DIGITS_PER_LINE; //4, to start
lines += (decimals % DIGITS_PER_LINE > 0) ? 1 : 0; //5, add a line for remainders
System.out.print("3");
System.out.println(decimals > 0 ? "." : "");
for (int line = 0; line < lines; line++) {
    int offset = line * DIGITS_PER_LINE; //line -> result, 0 -> 0, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, etc
    int digitsLeft = decimals - offset; //0 -> 42, 1 -> 32, ... , 4 -> 2
    int toPrint = digitsLeft % DIGITS_PER_LINE; //up to the requested digit amount
    for (int i = 0; i < toPrint; i++) {
        System.out.print(pi.charAt(offset + i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Remember integer arithmatic in code does not round; `49/10` is `4`, and `49%10` is `9` (the modulo or remainder operator).

The syntax `boolean ? "something" : "another"` is called a ternary statement, in case those are confusing I can rewrite this without them. You'll need to handle the user input and such, but never be afraid to break the problem down. Start with a program which can print x amount of digits for your input in a variable form, then work on the input. You could put something like this right in a method `printDigitsPI(int decimals)`. Most of the used variables above are constants, they won't change and don't need to be passed around.

As a last peice of advice, if you ever find yourself writing `num1`, `num2`, `num3`... as variables, there is quite likely a better way to go about it.

Comment: I don't understand ternary statements, but instead of modifying the code to exclude the ternary statement, can you explain them? That would be better.

Comment: They're basically like an if statement that provides a value. There's a lot of guides on them, but in basic terms: `boolean_expr ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

Comment: In summary, if(boolean = true) {value;}

Comment: My code just worked. Thanks for the idea. While it wasn't the solution, it got me incredibly close.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses Math.PI to create a String representation of the Double PI. We then determine where the decimal is at in that string using String#indexOf. We then request the number of decimals we would like to see using Scanner. Assuming the input is a non-negative integer we attempt to find the substring of the String PI using the initial index of "." and the remaining numbers.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        requestInput();
    }

    private static void requestInput() {
        String pi = Double.toString(Math.PI);

        int decimalOffset = pi.indexOf(".") + 1;

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of decimals of PI you would like to see: ");
            int decimals = scanner.nextInt();

            if (decimals < 0 || decimals > pi.length() + decimalOffset) {
                requestInput();
                return;
            }
            String result = pi.substring(0, decimals + decimalOffset);

            System.out.println(String.format("The result of PI with %s numbers is %s", decimals, result));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe this wouldn't correctly solve the OP's question. This would print everything onto a single line, whereas the question asks for multiple lines that are split into 10s (or less if the request isn't evenly divisible by ten).

Comment: Wow I completely skimmed over the question, my bad lads.